# Interactive background (presenting) view controller when presenting pageSheet

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit, presentviewcontroller

I'd like to ask you if there is any way to make presenting view controller interactive while presenting `pageSheet` vc. In the iOS 15 apple introduced detens for pageSheets and when pageSheet is in the `.medium()` state I'd like to be able to interact with the viewcontroller that's behind that sheet. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by setting `largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier` property on `UISheetPresentationController`
Here is an example of presenting `medium` detend with tappable viewcontroller that is behind the sheet:

```
private func presentModal() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let sheetVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SheetVC") as! SheetVC
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: sheetVC)
    // 1
    nav.modalPresentationStyle = .pageSheet
    // 2
    if let sheet = nav.sheetPresentationController {
        
        // 3
        sheet.detents = [.medium(), .large()]
        sheet.largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier = .medium
    }
    // 4
    present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

For more info I recommend [following article](https://sarunw.com/posts/bottom-sheet-in-ios-15-with-uisheetpresentationcontroller/)